# is there any performance difference between using malloc versus realloc?

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

I have this function:

```
int program_inc_capacity(Program *program)
{
    Instruction *v_old = program->v;

    size_t capacity_new = 2 * program->capacity;

    program->v = (Instruction *)malloc(capacity_new * sizeof(Instruction));
    if (program->v == NULL)
        return 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < program->size; i++)
    {
        program->v[i] = v_old[i];
    }

    free(v_old);

    program->capacity = capacity_new;

    return 1;
}
```

I call the above function when the memory previously allocated for program->v is no more enough. So I double it by reallocating the entire memory block through malloc.

Instead of using this approach I was thinking about using `realloc()`.
So the code would look something like this:

```
int program_inc_capacity(Program *program)
{
    Instruction *v_old = program->v;

    size_t capacity_new = 2 * program->capacity;

    Instruction *temp = (Instruction *)realloc(v_old, capacity_new * sizeof(Instruction));
    if (temp == NULL) {
        printf("Memory reallocation failed!\n");
        free(v_old);  // Free the original memory
        return 1;
    } else {
        v_old = temp;  // Update the pointer with the new memory location
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < program->size; i++)
    {
        program->v[i] = v_old[i];
    }

    free(v_old);

    program->capacity = capacity_new;

    return 1;
}
```

So, my question is: is there any performance difference? In which case is better the first approach over the second one and viceversa?
I also read that using realloc many times can lead to memory fragmentation.

Comment: Inside the standard library code `realloc()` may use *implementation tricks* which are not available to the compiler itself, making your implementation using `malloc()`, `memcpy()` and `free()` (when correctly implemented) at best equally performant ... and very probably less performant. `realloc()` does all the `malloc()`, `memcpy()` and `free()` by itself as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be quite a lot wrong with your use of `realloc()`

- Why do you `free(v_old);` on success?
- You have not replaced `program->v`
- `realloc()` copies the data for you - if the reallocation was successful, you must not access the old pointer value.
- The function always returns 1.

I suggest this simple re-write:

```
int program_inc_capacity(Program *program)
{
    size_t capacity_new = 2 * program->capacity;
    Instruction *temp = realloc(program->v, capacity_new * sizeof(Instruction));
    if (temp == NULL) {
        printf("Memory reallocation failed!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    program->v = temp;
    program->capacity = capacity_new;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> is there any performance difference?

Yes and it can be a big difference.

- When using `malloc` you are forced to copy the data from the old memory to the new memory.
- When using `realloc`, then `realloc` may be able to increase the allocated memory in-place. The returned pointer will then be pointing at the same address as your original pointer. No data will then need to be copied.

Note: In your implementation using `realloc` you seem to copy the old data and `free` the old pointer. That's not needed. `realloc` does that for you. Not only is it not needed: The old pointer is to be considered "dangling" and you shouldn't dereference or `free` what it points at.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there can be a performance difference.

If `realloc()` is able to resize in-place, then no copying of the contents is required.  That can reduce both the instantaneous memory use and the instruction count.

Even when a move is necessary, `realloc()` may have access to techniques that are unavailable to you (such as remapping virtual memory) to reduce its cost.

But your code is seriously broken, as [Weather Vane's answer](/a/76647419/4850040) explains.  You need to make it *correct* before you start comparing performance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's a (small) difference:

`realloc(3)` just reallocates the memory to a different place if there's no space on the heap to just extend the memory already allocated, so when no reallocation is needed, it runs faster than `malloc(3)`.

Also, when the reallocation is made to a different place, the contents of the previously allocated block have to be copied to the new place, so it will do extra work if you don't need the original contents copied.